# How to install Spark with anaconda distribution on ubuntu?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have Ubuntu  18.04.I am working with anaconda distribution for using jupyter notebooks and python.I want to install spark and pyspark to work with HDFS.
I want to know the proper installation procedure for the same.
Thank you

Comment: I tried using conda installation and manual installation but i am getting confused between setting up the environmnet variables in .bashrc file

Answer (score 2):

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```

This allows you to install PySpark into your anaconda environment using the conda-forge channel. In order for it to work with Spark, just run your code on the Spark cluster. For more information, look [here](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-scale/spark/) which has some references with using anaconda specifically with PySpark and Spark.

Comment: What changes i have to make in .bashrc file for setting up any variables?

Comment: The only ones I can imagine are ensuring that the PYTHONPATH and CONDA PATH variables are set properly - but if you can use python regularly with all the packages I don't see why that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thanks a lot.It started working.Actually i had tried using the conda installation but i was using a more upgraded version of java which was not compatible with spark 2.3.1.

Comment: Glad it started to work!